# arraylist sort and convert to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a simple class which is auto-generated and use to store responses from [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Anyway in the final step I would like to use row content, sort every element by position from highest to lowest and after sorting convert it to `String[]` with name only. How can I do that in the most efficient way?

```
public class RowModel implements Comparable<RowModel>{

    private String name;
    private double position;

    public double getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(float position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RowModel(String name, double position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

After my search online I found this method to execute sorting but I'm not sure that the results are correct. And of course I still don't know how to convert sorted names to `String[]` at the final step:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(RowModel rowModel) {
    double comparePosition = ((RowModel) rowModel).getPosition();
    return (int) (this.position- comparePosition);
}
```

Comment: You could use `Collections.sort( List<RowModel>... )` to sort, and there is more than one way to get `String[]` of names one of which is you could create an array of Strings and traverse the list and fill array with `it.next().getName()`

Answer (score 4):

Your compareTo method won't work as you are comparing double values and it will fail when integral parts of two values are same (i.e. when comparing 1.5 & 1.2 your comparator will return 0 but it should return 1).

for that you can use `Double.compare(d1, d2)`. you don't need to cast rowModel, too. Change your method as follow:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(RowModel rowModel) {
    double comparePosition = rowModel.getPosition();
    return Double.compare(this.position, comparePosition);
}
```

For Sorting you can use `Collections.sort(rowModels)`.

To convert this sorted list to list of names, you can use Stream API.

Assuming you have Sorted List of RowModel with name rowModels.

```
List<String> names = rowModels.stream().map(RowModel::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to convert this list to array,

```
String[] array = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
```

or directly,

```
String[] array = rowModels.stream().map(RowModel::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a list of rows `RowModel` in a variable named `rows`, you can easily do that using the Stream API:

```
List<String> names = rows.stream().sorted()
                       .map(row -> row.getName())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The intermediate step `sorted()` makes sure the stream is sorted, according to the `Comparable` implementation in your `RowModel` class, in this case.

Side note: Your `compareTo` implementation can be improved as it may be losing precision (casting `double` to `int` has the side effect of treating as `equal` two objects that aren't):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(RowModel rowModel) {
    double comparePosition = ((RowModel) rowModel).getPosition();
    double diff = this.position - comparePosition;

    return diff == 0 ? 0 : 
           (diff > 0 ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Comment: To compare doubles, just use the standard `static int Double.compare(double,double)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<RowModel> sortedModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
Collections.sort(sortedModels);
return sortedModels.toArray(new RowModel[0]);
```

**Edit:**
To actually return array of just names rather than whole `RowModel`s, you could do something like this:

```
String[] result = new String[sortedModels.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < sortedModels.size(); i++) {
    result.[i] = sortedModels.get(i).getName();
}
```

There is probably some shorter way to do this using Java 8 streams, but I'll leave that to someone who actually works with them.

Comment: Code-only answers are bad

Comment: sort works good but how to retrieve only names and send them to String[]?

Comment: I don't like `new RowModel[0]`. You have the length, so don't force the method to recreate an array. Technically, you already have an array with the correct size, so you could use it I guess.

Comment: @AxelH Yeah that was just me being lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Use util method of [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class, i.e

```
Collections.sort(list)
```

If you want to sort custom object you can use

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

see collections api